# Listview with custom adapter in fragment with tabs doesnt show the correct data

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs. Those tabs are the same fragment. It has a custom listView with two textviews and one imagebutton. So, I have an adapter and a class for each item. When i load the list, I want to show or not the button in base of a value in the item class. Well, when the Activity loads, that images just ignore the value and randomly shows or not.

This is the adapter(I have tried to fill the `holder.descripcion` with the value in `d.getEnlace()` and it show it correctly, but the button does what he wants):

```
public class documentoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Documento> {
    private final  ArrayList<Documento> lista;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String nombre, foto;

    public documentoAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<Documento> lista) {
        super(context, 0, lista);
        this.lista = lista;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final Documento d = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.documento, null);
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nombre =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textNombre);
        holder.descripcion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDescripcion);
        holder.enlace = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagenDescargar);
        holder.nombre.setText(d.getNombre());
        holder.descripcion.setText(Html.fromHtml(d.getDescripcion()));
        holder.descripcion.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        if(!(d.getEnlace().equals("null"))){
            holder.enlace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView nombre;
        TextView descripcion;
        ImageButton enlace;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }
    //public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    //    return false;
    //}
    public Documento getItem(int arg0) {
        return lista.get(arg0);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

The class of the items:

```
public class Documento {
    private String nombre, descripcion, enlace;
    private documentoAdapter adapter;

    public Documento(String nombre, String descripcion, String enlace) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.enlace = enlace;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getEnlace() {
        return enlace;
    }

    public documentoAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(documentoAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

}
```

and in the onCreate of the fragment I set the adapter like this:

```
    documentoAdapter adapter = new documentoAdapter(getActivity(), datos);
    ListView document_list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.documentListView);
    document_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
1. Your `ViewHolder` is pretty useless how it is right now. The idea is that you instantiate only one per `View` and then reuse it if the `View` is recycled.
2. Remember that the `View` for the list row gets recycled. So the Button could already be set to visible. You need to set it to invisible if you don't want to show it.

Comment: added `holder.enlace.setVisibility(View.GONE);` if it is not null and now it works! Thanks!